# Pairwise operation of 2 columns in datatable and replace them by new column's name

Tags: r, shiny, data.table

Let say i have a big data-table looking like this:

`Sequence  A1  B1  A2   B2
 s1         0   2   9   11
 s2         1   3   3   2
 s3         2   2   4   1
 s4         3   5   4   14
 s5         3   7   2   0
 s6         0   2   8   5
 .          .   .   .    .
 .          .   .   .    .
 .          .   .   .    .`

I want to compute some operation on it like log2(A2/A1) & log2(B2/B1) and return the data-table with column's names "A2/A1" and "B2/B1" looking like this:

`Sequence    A2/A1        B2/B1
 s1        log2(9/0)    log2(11/2)
 s2        log2(3/1)    log2(2/3)
 s3        log2(4/2)    log2(1/2)
 s4        log2(4/3)    log2(14/5)
 s5        log2(2/3)    log2(0/7)
 s6        log2(8/0)    log2(5/2)`

I've already found a workaround but it works ok. Since the selection of the column happens dynamically (in the UI), i can't really use that and i'm still getting all columns (A1, B1, A2, B2 and A2/A1 B2/B1).

```
selectInput("firstSelection", "Select First Factor", choices = "", multiple = T, 
helpText("First parameter for the calculation of Regulation-Factor")),
selectInput("secondSelection", "Select Second Factor", choices = "", multiple = T,
helpText("Second parameter for the calculation of Regulation-Factor"))
```

Hier is my workaround:

```
input_table <<- getData()[, paste(input$secondSelection, input$firstSelection,sep= "/"):=
list(get(input$secondSelection[1])/get(input$firstSelection[1]),
get(input$secondSelection[2])/get(input$firstSelection[2]))]
```

I guess it must be a better way to do that, may be using function like **apply** or parameter like **.I**, **.SD**, **.SDColms**. I read about them, but still don't really get how and when to use them.

Comment: It depends on the uploaded file. But since the user selects the columns to compute i can get it from the selected columns with "length(input$firstSelection)", which i check if it matches length(input$secondSelection) before even do anything

Comment: If the columns are of similar alternating order, then you can use the below solution

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `set` function which would be efficient for doing this operation.  Create the result dataset ('res') with the first column 'Sequence' from the original dataset with two columns occupied by NA.  Then, `set` the values in those columns by looping through the index specified in 'j1', subset the columns from 'dt1', divide and take the `log2`.

```
res <- data.table(Sequence = dt1$Sequence, A2A1= NA_real_, B2B1=NA_real_)
j1 <- as.integer(seq_len(uniqueN(sub("\\d+", "", names(dt1)[-1]))) + 1)

for(j in j1){
  set(res, i = NULL, j= j, value = log2(dt1[[j+2]]/dt1[[j]]))
}
res
#    Sequence       A2A1       B2B1
#1:       s1        Inf  2.4594316
#2:       s2  1.5849625 -0.5849625
#3:       s3  1.0000000 -1.0000000
#4:       s4  0.4150375  1.4854268
#5:       s5 -0.5849625       -Inf
#6:       s6        Inf  1.3219281

log2(9/0)
#[1] Inf
log2(11/2)
#[1] 2.459432
```

#### data

```
dt1 <- structure(list(Sequence = c("s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5", "s6"
 ), A1 = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 0L), B1 = c(2L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 
 2L), A2 = c(9L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 8L), B2 = c(11L, 2L, 1L, 14L, 
 0L, 5L)), .Names = c("Sequence", "A1", "B1", "A2", "B2"), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
setDT(dt1)
```

Comment: That's exactly what i didn't want to do... As i said, if the number of columns changes, i must also change the code. And since the user can upload any file, i have no chance to react to that. Still, thanks for answering

Comment: As i said... Your answer doesn't really help me right now. I rather stick with my workaround.